# Как из api забрать данные и записать в базу данных postgresql с помощью python?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, api, get

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import requests
import psycopg2
URL = 'url'
payload = {
    "secret_key": "",
    "company_id": '',
    "type":''
}

response = requests.get(
    URL,
    params=payload
)
json_in=response.json()

connection = psycopg2.connect(database="", user="", password="", host="", port=)
cursor = connection.cursor()

record = cursor.fetchall()
print("Data from Database:- ", record)
print(response.status_code)
print(json_in)
```

Я смогла вывести json, но вот как его дальше записать в таблицу не разобралась. Подскажите плиз как записать данные из api в postgresql базу? зы) гугл не помог((

Comment: вам дали один ответ, но я все таки хочу уточнить. А в каком именно виде вы хотите хранить данные? в моей голове есть несколько возможностей: JSON можно хранить как обычный текст в ячейке БД, можно разобрать JSON до БД и хранить так как вы хотите, можно использовать функционал postgres для работы с JSON (например jsonb поле)

Comment: @Елизавета если ответ данный t4kq вам подходит то пометьте его как решение. Если нет то добавьте пожалуйста комментарий.

Comment: @Dmitry изначально просто запись в поле с типом данных jsonb, затем буду парсить и записывать части дерева в другие поля

Comment: @SergeiMalanin на данный момент попробую воспользоваться ответом t4kq, если не получится - вернусь с вопросом)) спасибо)

Comment: @SergeiMalanin на самом деле если честно не очень понимаю ответ t4kq, потому что он прописывает запрос sql в общей форме, а ожидалось, что будет запись из api

Comment: @Елизавета а как я напишу Вам целый запрос, если я не знаю какие данные в ответ приходят?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтоб записать json в базу данных необходимо выполнить следующее

```
import psycopg2

try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(database="", user="", password="", host="", port="")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO yami(js1) VALUES ('{}')".format(json.dumps(json_in)))

    connection.commit()
    count = cursor.rowcount
    print(count, "Record inserted successfully into mobile table")

except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
    print("Failed to insert record into mobile table", error)

finally:
    # closing database connection.
    if connection:
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
```

Comment: вместо column_1 ... я меняю на название полей, а что вставлять вместо $s для values? что вставлять вместо data_1... для json_in?

Comment: @Елизавета Вы для начала приведите пример Вашей таблицы, пример JSON ответа от API. А после этого можно Вам помочь. Я предложил вариант "в слепую"

Comment: в задачку добавила скриншот) я понимаю наверно о чем вы) возможно ли записать json в одно поле одной строкой? мне бы просто понять как записать таким образом, а дальше я сама уже справлюсь)

Comment: @Елизавета я изменил ответ. Вам нужно просто вставлять свой JSON.

Comment: спасибо) сейчас попробую)

Comment: Failed to insert record into mobile table name 'json' is not defined
пишет ошибку

Comment: @Елизавета у вас есть телеграмм? Напишите мне `@t4kq2407`